# How to group Multivalued Value with LINQ?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, linq, solr

Im my model I have decleared value from wich I have to group, like this:

Note! Sender value is multivalued type

```
    private ICollection<string> _send;
    [SolrField("sender")]
    public ICollection<string> Sender
    {
        get 
        {
            if (_send == null)
            {
                return new Collection<string> { "" };
            }
            else
            {
                return _send;
            }
        }
        set { _send = value; }
    }
```

In my controller where I call Linq group code is:

```
var groups = matchingSpremenljivke.GroupBy(s => s.Sender);
foreach (IGrouping<string, SolrVariables> groups in gruph)
{
  ...
}
```

In foreach sentence I get this error:

```
"Unable to cast type 'Grouping 
[System.Collections.Generic.ICollection'1
[Sytem.String],MySoulution.Models.SolrVariables]'to type
'System.Linq.IGrouping'2[System.String,MySolution.Models.SolrVariables]'
```

This error shows only for variables that are multivalued, for non-multivalued type of variables this error is not shown.

my all code look like this now:

```
var grupe = matchingSpremenljivke.GroupBy(s => s.Sender);

foreach (IGrouping<ICollection<string>, SpremenljivkeSolr> grupa in grupe)
{
    List<SpremenljivkeSolr> tmpList = new List<SpremenljivkeSolr>();

    foreach (SpremenljivkeSolr tmpSolr in grupa)
    {
        tmpList.Add(tmpSolr);
    }

    SpremenljivkeSolr spremenljivkeSolr = new SpremenljivkeSolr();

    spremenljivkeSolr.Internal = tmpList[tmpList.Count - 1].Internal;
    spremenljivkeSolr.Exchangetimestamp = tmpList[tmpList.Count - 1].Exchangetimestamp;
    spremenljivkeSolr.Order = tmpList[0].Order;
    spremenljivkeSolr.Exchangetimestamp2 = tmpList[0].Exchangetimestamp;
    spremenljivkeSolr.MsgT = tmpList[0].MsgT;
    spremenljivkeSolr.Sender = tmpList[tmpList.Count - 1].Sender;

    seznam.Add(spremenljivkeSolr);

}
```

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the type of `Sender` property is `ICollection<string>`, this query:

```
var groups = matchingSpremenljivke.GroupBy(s => s.Sender);
```

returns an `IGrouping<ICollection<string>,SolrVariables>` not `IGrouping<string, SpremenljivkeSolr>`. Change `string` to `ICollection<string>` in `foreach` or use `var`.

Also are you sure you want to group your values based on an `ICollection<T>` without providing an `IEqualityComparer<T>` implementation ?